# What does this tombstone say?

Tags: перевод

[image]

Hello there!  Would someone be so kind as to translate the words on the tombstone?  It would really help in finding answers to my family tree.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

`Злотникова` (Zlotnikova) is the family name, a feminine form of `Злотников` (Zlotnikov). `Софья` (Sofia) is the first name, which is a common Russian feminine name. `Львовна` (Lvovna) is the patronym, meaning that her father's name was `Лев` (Lev), or, before the 1917 orthographic reform, `Левъ`. Then there are dates of birth and death.  As common in Russian, the month is written in Roman numerals, while the day is in Hindu-Arabic numerals, so 8.III means March 8.  In Russian, the day should precede the month.

The text is:

```
Dear 
Mommy!
You will
always live in
our hearts.
From the husband,
children,
nephews 
and relatives.
```

Comment: It's "Mommy" not mummy :)

Comment: @InitK, thanks, I've understood now. `mummy` is a British variant, and `mommy` is an American one